# how do i make tkinter update

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an entry field that stores my list to a text file
when i press the button to store the info, it gets stored but i have to restart the app to see it on the options menu
How do i make the app update without having to restart it?
`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("test tool") #App Title
root.iconbitmap("D:\\Software\\GigaPixel Frames\\Dump\\New folder\\imgs\\Logo.ico")
root.geometry("1600x800") #App Dimensions

DropDownvar = StringVar(value="Select an option")
DropDownvar.set("Select an option")

my_list = open("Characters.txt").readlines()
DropDownMenu = OptionMenu(root, DropDownvar, *my_list)
DropDownMenu.pack()

inputBox = Entry(root)
inputBox.pack()

def ButtonFun():
  InputBoxEntry = inputBox.get()
  with open("Characters.txt", "a") as text_file:
      text_file.write(InputBoxEntry + "\n")
  root.update()
inputBoxButton = Button(root, text="Input", command=ButtonFun)
inputBoxButton.pack()







root.mainloop()
```

`

could not find answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the input item to the dropdown manually inside `ButtonFun()`.

Also using `.readlines()` will not strip out the trailing newline `'\n'` from each line in the file, better use `.read().splitlines()` instead:

```py
...
with open("Characters.txt") as f:
    my_list = f.read().splitlines()
DropDownMenu = OptionMenu(root, DropDownvar, *my_list)
DropDownMenu.pack()
...
def ButtonFun():
  InputBoxEntry = inputBox.get()
  with open("Characters.txt", "a") as text_file:
      text_file.write(InputBoxEntry + "\n")
  # add the input item to dropdown
  DropDownMenu["menu"].add_command(label=InputBoxEntry, command=lambda: DropDownvar.set(InputBoxEntry))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should re-read and update your list after you put input and added line. You should avoid using my_list = open("Characters.txt") as you may forget to close it. Or sometimes it gives an error and stay unclosed which you cannot perform anything over it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("test tool") #App Title
root.geometry("1600x800") #App Dimensions

DropDownvar = StringVar(value="Select an option")
DropDownvar.set("Select an option")


DropDownMenu = OptionMenu(root, DropDownvar," ")
DropDownMenu.pack()

inputBox = Entry(root)
inputBox.pack()

def fillOptionMenu():
    with open("characters.txt","r") as f:
        my_list = f.readlines()

    DropDownMenu["menu"].delete(0,"end")
    # DropDownMenu.set_menu(my_list)
    for i in my_list:
        DropDownMenu["menu"].add_command(label=i, command=lambda value=i: DropDownvar.set(i))

def ButtonFun():
    InputBoxEntry = inputBox.get()
    with open("Characters.txt", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(InputBoxEntry + "\n")
    root.update()

    fillOptionMenu()


inputBoxButton = Button(root, text="Input", command=ButtonFun)
inputBoxButton.pack()

fillOptionMenu()

root.mainloop()
```